# A series of independent if statements in haskell

Tags: haskell, if-statement

Probably a silly question but I can't for the life of me figure this out.

I want to append to the end of a list based on a series of if statements.

In python (or most other languages I am familiar with) I could do something like this:

```
x = ["hi"]
if True:
    x.append("hello")
if not True:
    x.append("wait a minute...")
if True:
    x.append("goodbye")
```

Which would give me:

```
['hi', 'hello', 'goodbye']
```

How does one achieve such a thing in Haskell?

I can get as far as:

```
res :: [[Char]]
res =
    let x = ["Hi"]
    in
        if (True)
            then x ++ ["hello"]
            ... what goes here???
        else x
```

Or am I going about this totally wrong?

I am very new to Haskell so please don't bite...

Comment: There is no Python-like "append" in Haskell because Haskell values are immutable. `++` is "concatenate" (Python's `+`), not "append". It returns a new list without touching either argument. If-then-else in Haskell is more like Python ternary operator than Python if-then-else. So it may be helpful to rewrite your Python code such that no variable gets changed, and no if-then-else statement is used (use the ternary instead). It should be a single expression, not a series of statements. Then you might be able to translate it to Haskell more or less directly.

Comment: I am trying to build a list based on the boolean return from a series of functions. I only want to add to the list when I get a True return.

Comment: Um, I know what you are trying to do. I'm telling you how to do that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Idiomatically,

```
x = concat [ [ "hi" ],
             [ "hello" | True ],
             [ "wait a minute..." | not True ],
             [ "goodbye" | True ] ]
```

Comment: or without the `concat`, just with interspersed `++`s. :)

Comment: How is that notation called with the pipe and the condition?

Comment: @CodingEdgar, it's just an abnormally simple [list comprehension](https://wiki.haskell.org/List_comprehension)

Answer (score 6):

In Haskell every `if` expression **must** have an `else` clause. In that regard it's similar to the Python conditional operator:

```py
a if test else b
```

In Haskell it would be written as:

```hs
if test then a else b
```

So how do you write the following in Haskell?

```py
x = ["hi"]
if True:
    x.append("hello")
```

You would do something like:

```
let x = ["hi"] in
if True then x ++ ["hello"] else x
```

See the `else` clause? It just returns the value as is.

---

However writing code like this sucks. We want to write code like in Python, and Python is stateful. The variable `x` is the state. In Haskell we have the `State` monad for writing code like that. Consider:

```
import Control.Monad.State

append a = modify (++ [a])

foo :: [String] -> [String]
foo = execState $ do
    when True       $ append "hello"
    when (not True) $ append "wait a minute..."
    when True       $ append "goodbye"

x = ["hi"]

res = foo x

main = print res
```

Simple right?

Answer (score 6):

In addition to @AaditMShah's answer, if you only want to append to a value, without other modifications, the [writer monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Writer-Lazy.html) would be the proper abstraction:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Writer

append :: a -> Writer [a] ()
append = tell . (: [])

x :: [String]
x = execWriter $ do
        tell ["hi"]
        when True $
            append "hello"
        when (not True) $
            append "wait a minute..."
        when True $
            append "goodbye"
```

Answer (score 5):

Haskell is different than the way it is done in Python or other languages:

- List (and most other data structures) are immutable.
- `if else` is an expression in Haskell as opposed to statement which is seen in other languages. You cannot ignore the `else` part in Haskell like what you did with Python.

Looking at your python code, it seems what you want to do is that if the condition is `True`, then you want to append an element to the list. That pattern can be abstracted in the following function:

```
appendIfTrue :: Bool -> a -> [a] -> [a]
appendIfTrue b x xs = if b
                      then xs ++ [x]
                      else xs
```

Once you have written the function you can achieve the same functionality using the following code:

```
x = ["hi"]

main = do
  let x1 = appendIfTrue True "hello" x
      x2 = appendIfTrue False "wait a minute" x1
      x3 = appendIfTrue True "goodbye" x2
  print x3
```

The thing to note here that is you are creating a new list here instead of modifying them as you did in your Python code.
Demo:

```
λ> main
["hi","hello","goodbye"]
```

Comment: Why write code like `let x1 = f x; x2 = g x1; x3 = h x2` when you can use the `State` monad?

Comment: @AaditMShah By reading the question, it seems that OP is a beginner in Haskell. State Monad is definitely elegant, but I don't know if a beginner could digest that. :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to understand that in Haskell you cannot just modify x as in your python example. You need to thread a value (a list of Strings) though your conditionals, where each step appends or does not append another String. So you can't get away with nested if-then-else statement alone. You need access to the intermediate List of Strings built so far.

So the elementary operation is to append or not append a String to a List of Strings based on a boolean. A function which does this kind of conditionall appending could look like:

```
condAppend :: Bool -> String -> [String] -> [String]
condAppend c suff pref = if c then pref ++ [suff]
                         else pref
```

No you just have to chain a series of condAppends and apply it to an inial List of Strings:

```
res = condAppend True "goodby" 
      $ condAppend False "wait a minute" 
      $ condAppend True "hello" ["Hi"]
```

This gives you:

```
["Hi","hello","goodby"]
```

Note that the order of execution in res is bottom to top (or right to left if you write it all in one line) or inside-out if you like as as in `f (g (h x))` where the leftmost function `f` is applied last.

If you don't like that, you need an alternative to ($) which operates left to right. You can write your own function (>>>) as in

```
res'= (
       condAppend True "hello"
       >>>
       condAppend False "wait a minute"
       >>>
       condAppend True "goodbye"
      ) ["Hi"]
        where
            f >>> g = g . f
```

and it so happens that (a much generalized version of) (>>>) is already defined in Control.Arrow.

Comment: you can also define `(|>) x f = f x` and move `["Hi"]` to the top as well, with it. Or with `($ ["Hi"]) $ ...`.